# Model Binding ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have a method like the following

```
  [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
  [RequiresAuthentication()]
  public JsonResult SomeEvent(ClientObject myObject)
  {

   }
```

On my localhost/DEV/QA box the model binding works perfectly.  However, when I move this to my production server, no dice.  However if I change it to

```
  [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
  [RequiresAuthentication()]
  public JsonResult SomeEvent(string value1, string value2)
  {

   }
```

It works perfectly on production.  In other words it seems like the ModelBinding is not working.

Some difference in the environments.

1. On local/dev/qa System.Web.MVC is in the GAC but on my production it's in the BIN.
2. On prod site is in a web farm but there is 1 primary server getting the traffic.  The other is a fail over.

System.Web.MVC does not need to be in the GAC for model binding to work correct?

Seems strange.  Any ideas what could prevent ModelBinding to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Check your View page what does it inherit from if anything? Does the View on the server match up with the view on your localhost box?

For Instance:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Mvc2Testing.Models.Customer>" %>
```

What does yours look like? Although the problem is more likely in another file different elsewhere, you didn't specify if you are wiping the target directory on each deployment, or just copying this one dll.